# XSLT - Occurence of an attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following xml:

```
<Books>   
 <Book author="John" country="Norway"/>   
 <Book author="Paul" />    
 <Book author="Steve" country="England"/>      
</Books>
<Books>       
 <Book author="George" />    
 <Book author="Thomas" country="Germany"/>   
</Books>
```

I want to find the position of the attribute "country" inside each "Books" element.

```
<Books>   
 <Book author="John" country="Norway"/>    --1
 <Book author="Paul" />    
 <Book author="Steve" country="England"/> --2
 <Book author="Bob" country="Denmark"/>  --3  
</Books>
<Books>       
 <Book author="George" />    
 <Book author="Thomas" country="Germany"/>  --1 
</Books>
```

Which XPath function can we use for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can count the number of preceding siblings with that attribute, here is a template showing that:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="Books/Book[@country]">
  <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::Book[@country]) + 1"/> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="Books">
     <xsl:apply-templates select=".//@country"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@country">
  <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
  <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document (made well-formed):**

```
<t>
<Books>
 <Book author="John" country="Norway"/>    --1
 <Book author="Paul" />
 <Book author="Steve" country="England"/> --2
 <Book author="Bob" country="Denmark"/>  --3
</Books>
<Books>
 <Book author="George" />
 <Book author="Thomas" country="Germany"/>  --1
</Books>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
1
2
3
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XPath count function:

```
count(/Books/Book/@country)
```

Comment: "count" returns the total number of occurrences of "country". I want to know the position of this attribute.

Comment: @saravana_pc - count is a summary function. position cannot be retrieved with a summary function.

Comment: @Suresh - I agree that "count" cannot be used. Hence wanted to know how to solve this.

Comment: @saravana_pc Sorry, I misunderstood your question. Martin's answer is what I would have done as well.

Comment: @saravana_pc - What country attribute of the books element are you trying to get the position? You input xml has multiple countries. If you want to get the position as well, please update your question with the detail of the kind of output you wish to see.